# Text-align center and negative margin

Tags: css, margin

With HTML/css I tried the following layout:

[image: https://imgur.com/r9vmNra,3RnM6tr#0]

Green boxes are images, blue ones are text.

I want to center all the boxes. The text boxes should jump of the raster so that they will overlay the image, if there is one left next to it.

I tried this with negative margin, but this won't work for the last row you see on my picture. It looks like the negative left margin wont work for the first text box in that row.

For now it looks like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/r9vmNra,3RnM6tr#1]

Can someone tell me whats to problem and how to solve it?

Comment: add your code plz, it is really more usefull than just image

Comment: as i use a CMS full of divs and spans i think it would pretty nice to paste that html and css here. but i think its a more general question about how using negative margin while having text-align center on the outer element

Comment: We can't tell you how to use negative margins unless we can see what you're actually doing. Please post your code in your question.

Comment: can't tell you what is wrong with your car just by looking at the outside, give us code to work with

Comment: Rule number 6.) There are no blue boxes.